# Buildozer: manually include an external API

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'd like to include an SDK library into the build that does not exist in PIP, or any public place on the Internet. I've read that this can be done manually. I put the SDK library in the root of my Kivy project. The development console finds this import just fine. The problem is with the deployment.

Looking at the buildozer.spec file I came across this:

```
# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy
```

I have the SDK in a folder called sdk in the root of my project, hence I tried this:

requirements.source.sdk = sdk

It compiles without errors, but the application crashes when trying to import it.

How do I manually include an SDK library in to my APK?

Comment: Have you tried to look into the logs for the error when application crashes? well if not then try `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat > logcat.txt` to directly deploy your application and also don't forget to on the USB debugging on your phone.

Comment: also this link might help https://github.com/tito/2048/blob/master/buildozer.spec

Comment: In order for that to work I need the Kivy Launcher App and an SD card right?

Comment: No! you don't need kivy launcher app or SD card for this :) .. go though this gist file for full procedure. https://gist.github.com/kiok46/06add5048882e6504895

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. Turns out the library was indeed included already. So the answer to the question is that all I have to do is put the SDK folder in my project folder. Feel free to answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just a small observation that once the app is on the device in question, you can simply type 'adb logcat > log.txt' in the console and immediately run the app on the device rather than having to build again each time you run logcat(unless you changed the app of course). Then ctrl+c to stop logcat when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well! you already figured out the answer that's **put the SDK folder in your project folder.**

I write this answer to help someone in future. :)

Whenever you deploy an application on your device, using logs is always easy and useful.

Even if you want to see the print statements in your application you would always find logs useful.

So, here's how you do it.

you need to use adb server.

1. Connect your android with your laptop/pc.
2. Got to developer options and turn on the stay awake and USB debugging options
3. In your terminal type sudo adb-kill server then sudo adb-start server.
4. Type adb devices(this should give list of devices connected)

> List of devices attached
>
> you_device_name device

5. cd to your folder where you have made your build.
6. Type `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat > logcat.txt`
   this saves the logs (for the entire process) in a file logcat.txt in the same folder.
   go through it and find your error.
7. Keep your phone awake.(do not lock it).

Happy coding :)